# Is there a way for when I hover over the avatar image text slides in?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So pretty much I have a avatar that is floating up and down, but I also want to add a way for when you hover over it, text will slide in that says my name. I don't care if it is JavaScript or CSS, I also want to keep the hover animation that happen when you hover over the image.
Here is my code so far.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Floating Avatar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css">
    <script src="./js/main.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="avatar">
                <img src="assets/images/avatar.png" alt="avatar" class="avatarimage"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #FDBB2D 0%, #3A1C71 100%);
}

h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #eeeeee;
}

p {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: light;
    color: #333333;
}

span a {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #cccccc;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 10px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    &:hover {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
}

@keyframes float {
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        transform: translatey(0px);
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow: 0 25px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        transform: translatey(-20px);
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        transform: translatey(0px);
    }
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.avatar {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 5px white solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    transform: translatey(0px);
    animation: float 6s ease-in-out infinite;
    img { width: 1000%; height: auto; }
}

.avatarimage:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.avatarimage {
    width: 100%;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally possible with CSS and isn't that hard to accomplish since you already have overflow hidden set on your `.avatar` class.

Basically you'll just add your name inside `.avatar`:

```html
<div class="avatar">
    <img src="assets/images/avatar.png" alt="avatar" class="avatarimage" />
    <p class="avatarname">Your Name</p>
  </div>
```

Then, you'll add the CSS to transition that in on the hover of `.avatar`:

```css
.avatarname {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.avatar:hover .avatarname {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

You'll also need to add `position: relative;` to your `.avatar` CSS.

[Here's an example on codepen](https://codepen.io/davidleininger/pen/MWXoRNv/c21853cd27194342d0748063edf5cbec)

This works, but there are some other things that we can clean up. You have a few things defined in a few places. Your `img` styles for example, that could be in one place, especially since you're using SCSS. Here is a cleaned up example for you:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fdbb2d 0%, #3a1c71 100%);
}

@keyframes float {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 25px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transform: translatey(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.avatar {
  animation: float 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  border: 5px white solid;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  transform: translatey(0px);
  width: 150px;
}
.avatar img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.avatar .avatarname {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.avatar:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
.avatar:hover .avatarname {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520423465871-0866049020b7?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2Njg0NjUwNjI&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80" alt="avatar" class="avatarimage" />
    <p class="avatarname">Your Name</p>
  </div>
</div>
```